# How to get url without page

Tags: javascript, html, string, dom

I want to get url without page. Please see it below.

current url

```
http://localhost/FolderPath/Page.html
```

want to get

```
http://localhost/FolderPath/
```

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var oldPath = 'http://localhost/FolderPath/Page.html';
var newPath = oldPath.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/') + '/';
```

Comment: To add to that: in place of `oldPath` use `document.baseURI` if you wish to dynamically grab the current page's URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
"http://localhost/FolderPath/Page.html".replace(/[^\/]*$/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "http://localhost/FolderPath/Page.html";
url = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex anyone?

```
var url = "http://localhost/FolderPath/Page.html";
url.match(/(.+)(\/(.+)?)$/)[1] + "/";

//returns "http://localhost/FolderPath/"

var url = "http://localhost/FolderPath/";
url.match(/(.+)(\/(.+)?)$/)[1] + "/";

//returns "http://localhost/FolderPath/"
```